# Does Thor's power come from Asgard?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, we see Thor and The Valkyrie discuss about his returning to Asgard. She says if Hela is truly there then Asgard is doomed. She also went on to say "Hela draws her power from Asgard as well as you." Is this true and if so what is the case now that Asgard is destroyed?

Comment: Note that, at the end of the movie, Odin said that "Asgard is not a place, but the people that make it". So, Asgard lives!

Comment: This is all based on Valkyrie's comments, but bear in mind that Valkyrie has been in exile for longer than almost any living Asgardian has been alive (things must have changed in her absence). We observe in Ragnarok, and Infinity War, that Thor's abilities seem unaffected by the status of Asgard. If anything he might be stronger following the events of forging Stormbreaker.

Answer (score -2):

Hela draws her power from Asgard but not Thor. In the same movie Odin says that the hammer was just a instrument to help you with your powers, the real power in inside of you.

Comment: Odin never actually comments on where Thor's power comes from. From the [script](http://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/thor_ragnarok.pdf): "ODIN (CONT’D) - That hammer helped you control your power, focus it. But it was never the source of your strength." So, this answer could be wrong because it's only source doesn't actually verify your statement.

Answer (score -2):

Thor draws his power from Asgard. As Odin says in the movies Asgard was never a place but its people. Thus Thor draws his strength from all Asgardians. When Thanos killed 50% of the Asgardians Thor lost roughly half his power. That's why he sought out Stormbreaker to augment his power. As Asgard prospers again on earth Thor's power will grow once again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your answer needs to provide some evidence instead of stating the points of the question as facts.

Comment: I just watched Ragnarok for the 6th time. It was repeated many times by Odin and Heimdall and eventually Thor. Asgard is not a place it is the people. That's why Thor doesn't mind destroying his world by summoning Surtur. He says so long as Asgardians survive that's all that matters. Odin also said Thor draws his power from "Asgard" he did not specifically state the people but if you add both quotes together you come to the logical conclusion.

Comment: Additionally in Infinity War when Thor held the star forge open it was clear to me that the star blast took out part of his essence and imbued it into Stormbreaker. That's why Eitri says he needs the axe to regenerate and why it healed him.

Comment: There are some very bold statements there. Can you back any of them up with evidence  from the films or supplementary materials?

Comment: _”That's why he sought out Stormbreaker”_ hmm no, he sought it out for a Thanos killing weapon and because he doesn’t have his previous one anymore.

Comment: Yes he needed something to augment his power since he was unable to kill Thanos plus he was significantly weaker in End Game. People wanted to blame it on being FatThor out of shape but I believe it was because he lost a lot of Asgardians 5 years ago. I have no evidence but I have seen many "deities" powers that grow or fall based on their worshippers. Ares from Wonder Woman. Olympians from Clash of Titans. Etc. I believe the Asgardians' life force fuel Thor's power on a similar way.

Comment: @Colonels, Odin never said that Thor draws his power from Asgard, he just said that about Hela.

Answer (score -2):

As it has been stated in the other answers, Odin specifies that Asgard is not a place, but its people.

The difference between Hela and Thor was this knowledge of where *exactly* their power came from. Hela was obsessed with placing herself on the throne of Asgard, to become the Queen of Asgard. She believed (as did Loki, originally) this was the seat of "ultimate power". Thor, on the other hand was told that Asgard is just a place, and what good is a place, if there are no people? This, along with the lesson he was taught about Mjolnir (it is only a tool to help direct his power, not the source of it), was the difference between Thor and Hela. Which is why Thor was intent on saving the people, and Hela directed her attention toward Surtur as he was summoned to destroy Asgard, while the rest escaped.

Following the release of the final movies, we can see a significant difference in Thor's power. After Thanos carries out his wish, and "snaps" half of all life out of existence, Thor is slow, lazy and fat. After they travel through time, and "un-snap" everyone that was removed, not only does Thor show his true colors once again, but also has a significant increase in power. This is because the original population of Asgard has been restored.

Comment: I’ve downvoted unless you can find evidence that Thor was like he was in Endgame because he was lacking power. It seems to me he was that way because he was simply depressed.

Answer (score -3):

**Thor: Ragnarok** was perhaps the least comic-accurate Marvel movie to date, however, given that the rest of the MCU has stayed pretty true to the comics, the answer to your question should keep with what we know from the comics.

In the comics, Thor is Asgardian, which means he possesses the above-human strength, speed, endurance, invulnerability, etc. based solely on his physiology. "Thor’s unique physiology of half-Asgardian and Half Elder God grants him the typical powers of an Asgardian God but he is much stronger than the typical members of his race" (Comicvine).

Here's a link to a more in-depth discussion of his powers: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/thor/4005-2268/

Since his abilities are mostly due to this, he should retain all of his natural abilities (including weather manipulation) even after the destruction of Asgard. Mjolnir did assist with some of his natural abilities, and even gave him some new abilities like flight, so with the destruction of Mjolnir, we may see a flightless Thor in Infinity War. But the destruction of Asgard should not have taken away any of Thor's abilities, since they are based on his physiology and not on the existence of Asgard.

Comment: Hmm, just after his lightning attack on Hel, he did used his power to descent on Bifrost, and Odin said that hammer was only a focus of power, so Thor should be able to fly if he masters using his power without Mjollnir.

Comment: Oh interesting. Thank you for adding that. Yes, then it seems that Mjolnir mainly (exclusively?) acts as a focus for his powers, rather than giving him any new ones. So rather than a flightless Thor, perhaps we will see a more raw, uncontrolled Thor. That could be really interesting, especially in the realm of weather manipulation.