# Why didn't Thor lose his power?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, Valkyrie told Thor this about Hela:

> Her power comes from Asgard the same as yours

Thor's plan was to unleash Surtur who destroys Asgard, which weakens Hela allowing Surtur to kill her.

But why didn't that weakened Thor as well? We saw him later in *Avengers: Infinity War* very powerful.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182795/does-thors-power-come-from-asgard

Comment: @Paulie_D - The two questions are dupes, but none of the answers on the other questions are upvoted. I've voted to close that as a dupe of this.

Comment: I can reopen, but I can't find the quotation anymore 

Comment: @uhoh Undeleted.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I've commented there, added an Elon Musk tweet to the comment and started the reopen process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asgard is the people not the place. Odin states this in the same film and I believe Thor reiterates it later on. As such as Asgard is still around then he wouldn’t lose his powers. And of course there is also New Asgard in Norway that we could argue is the (new) place as well.

> **Odin:** Asgard is not a place. Never was. This could be Asgard. Asgard is where our people stand. Even now, right now, those people need your help.
>
> <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok*</sub>

In my opinion I don’t think Surtur destroying Asgard weakened Hela so he could destroy her. His sword actual goes straight through her, presumably killing her, before he plunges it into Asgard’s centre. And as we saw Hela was still incredibly powerful at that point. Surtur kills her *before* destroying Asgard, the place.

Comment: But that leaves the same issue, Asgard is the people, and the people died by Thanos on his attack, why Thor is still powerful?

Comment: @Mocas Thanos only killed half on the ship, have you not watched Endgame? And to be honest I’d be surprised if the whole thing isn’t a my least somewhat metaphorical.

Comment: I think Thanos killed all the people on the ship when he attacked it and got the stone off Loki. They didn't die off the snap.

Comment: @Mocas He didn't kill them all. We see Valkyrie, Korg, Miek and other Asgardians in New Asgard in Endgame. They escaped via an escape pod.,